# Use a favicon for each host via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, favicon

I have 2 server alias poiting to the same folder and using the same .htaccess, what I want to do is to use different favicons for each server alias.

I tried with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_HOST} ^myhost.com$
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ /images/favicon1.ico
```

But i'm still not able to make it work

Any answer, tip or solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use HTTP_HOST instead of REQUEST_HOST. To make different favicon.ico for 2 different alias, you can try below configuration to make to work...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost.com$
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ /images/favicon1.ico

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mynewhost.com$
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ /images/favicon2.ico
```

this way you can make it work... i tried on my domain and it works... :)

Comment: Because of the rules I had in my htaccess I had to add an [L] for it to work. This signals that no further rules should be applied after that one.